# How to use Google Script to send an email with information collected from Google Form?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

**For reference:** Here is [my Google Form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/15h_TjyZcI_x2c8Pql3lLHA8d_sx4haqrRJXriAIpwoY/viewform?edit_requested=true).

Here is [a Google PE Blank Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W0XUtp4SqPuIVtJ96qpK7hhg67mA3rbXf5O-WHDlyXc/edit#gid=1902874127) which has been tied to the output of my Google Form (answers will output on tab Form Responses 2).

---

I've built up a Google Form capable of collecting a good bit of data. It is meant to be filled out by a manager requesting SAP permissions for a new hire.

They proceed through the Form and enter their primary department (SAP Stream) which leads them to the next page/section that allows the manager to check off what the employee's required permissions will be.

Sometimes, an employee will interface with multiple departments, so the option for a supporting/secondary SAP Stream exists on the second page. This can be continued as needed until all of an employee's requisite roles/permissions are collected in a Google Sheet.

In the Sheet, you will see that:

- Columns A-F include basic information
- Columns H-T are for the Job Responsibilities
- Columns U-AG are a range for the information of one's Supporting SAP Stream
- Columns AH-AT are the Supporting SAP Stream's Job Responsibilities
- Columns AU-BG collect the Secondary Supporting SAP Stream

I had built Google Script language to collect each of these bits of information in variables which would then get declared as global variables so they could be passed along to an HTML page in the App Script.

Finally, an email consisting of this HTML page would be sent out to the manager in charge of designating SAP permissions.

In previous iterations (which were much simpler), I used an IF statement to check whether a column at the end of the row was empty.

```
      // Loop over the rows
  data.forEach((row,i) => {

    // Identify whether notification has been sent
    if (row[59] === '') {
```

If it was, the Script would check the Sheet, collecting all of the aforementioned information, and send an email. Then, it would populate that last cell with "Notification Sent" so that the next time the Form was submitted and the Script checked, it would skip sending out a redundant email (and we would have a record that the process went through successfully).

The latest version included variables for

```
        function jobResponsibilities(a){
      var z = a.range.getRow();
      var valuesA = a.range.getSheet().getRange(z,8,1,13).getValues();
      var jobResponsibilities = valuesA.join(' ');
      console.log(jobResponsibilities);
    }
      
    function supportingSAP(b){
      var y = b.range.getRow();
      var valuesB = b.range.getSheet().getRange(y,21,1,13).getValues();
      var supportingSAP = valuesB.join(' ');
    }
      
    function secondaryJob(c){
      var x = c.range.getRow();
      var valuesC = c.range.getSheet().getRange(x,34,1,13).getValues();
      var secondaryJob = valuesC.join(' ');
    }
      
    function secondarySAP(d){
      var w = d.range.getRow();
      var valuesD = d.range.getSheet().getRange(w,47,1,13).getValues();
      var secondarySAP = valuesD.join(' ');
    }
```

Collecting the four varying types of information. I used a [getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) in order to scope out the exact parts of the Sheet which would have this information and join them together so that the variable could be pulled into the email in a simple table format.

**For some reason, upon Form submission, the Notification IF doesn't seem to be running and the email never gets sent.**

**Is it a problem with the way I've ordered things? Did I improperly build the functions off what you showed me? Is it something as simple as my brackets at the bottom?**

Comment: If you're using an onFormSubmit then all of the values for a submission are in e.namedValues() and e.values().  You don't need to read the row from the linked sheet,  the information has already been given to you.

Comment: How are your functions tied to the form submission trigger?

Comment: You surmised correctly that I am using onFormSubmit for my trigger. 

Can you elaborate on what you mean as far as the values being in e.namedValues() and e.values()? What kind of code would I want to be able to call up in order to have those individual entries be recalled in the format I have in the HTML page?